# URL query string behaves differently

Tags: angular, routes

I have routing **`app routing`** like below

```
{
  path: 'services',            
  loadChildren: './services/services-home.module#ServicesHomeModule'
}
```

and in the **`service module`** I have routing like below

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ServiceHomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: ':slug/:id',
    component: ServiceCategoryComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',

  },

  {
    path: 'vendor/:id',
    component: VendorAddressComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
```

I'm successfully routing to my **`ServiceCategoryComponent`** upto here it is working perfectly.

But when I'm redirecting to **`VendorAddressComponent`**, the **`URL`**(/services/vendor/10) is successfully changing but where as the component is not loading(but I'm still there in same page)

If suppose if change my routing for  **`ServiceCategoryComponent,`** to like below

```
  {
    path: '/sydney/:slug/:id', // if I place any other string instead of sydney it is working fine.
    component: ServiceCategoryComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  }
```

May I know the what causing weird behaviour? how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Route must be reordered as below

```
{
    path: '',
    component: ServiceHomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'vendor/:id',
    component: VendorAddressComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
  {
    path: ':slug/:id',
    component: ServiceCategoryComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',

  }
```

**:slug/:id** matches **vendor/:id** route as well.

Comment: yeah it's working fine, can you please tell me what might be the reason ?

Comment: Angular goes with first route match, so :slug/:id matches any xxxx/xxxx route. Such wildcard routes must be added at the last to avoid such issues.